# Create internet browser shortcut which logs into ebay account

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks

I've got two accounts for eBay, a personal and a work account. I'm forever swapping accounts on a daily basis. I wondered whether 2 bookmarks could be created on my desktop. The bookmarks would correspond to a specific account, opening a shortcut would direct me to the eBay home page signed in to the account assigned to that shortcut.

Looking for a solution to fit either: Internet Explorer or Chrome

Comment: How about using 2 different browsers? Or since you mentioned Chrome - one Chrome attached with your gmail account (sign in to Chrome), and another version of Chrome (or different sign in) for the other ebay account? Or use password manager so you can easily auto fill your multiple accounts?

Comment: Yes, that would work! It's a simple solution too. Thank you. I'm going leave the question open still, I'm interested to see whether someone offers an answer which would involve script writing...

Comment: Darius, by 'another version of Chrome' , you of course mean 'another Chrome profile' ?      As for a script to do it (after saving both ebay logins in the same Chrome profile), it should be pretty trivial to record an AutoIT script for logging in to both accounts.

Comment: Just looked into AutoIT, never heard of it before. Very interesting!! Thanks